# How to insert text alternatively from two files with a common pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have two files...

First File Input...

```
1 How many steps are in programming?
A.5
B.4
C.3
D.9
Ans.

2 How many stairs in room?
A.6
B.10
C.15
D.23
Ans.
```

Second File Input...

```
1. Who is outside of the room ?
A.john
B.Mary
C.Scot
D.Fery
Ans.

2. Which day is today ?
A.Mon
B.Wed
C.Friday
D.Sunday
Ans.
```

I need Output like...

```
1 How many steps are in programming?
A.5
B.4
C.3
D.9
Ans.

1. Who is outside of the room ?
A.john
B.Mary
C.Scot
D.Fery
Ans.

2 How many stairs in room?
A.6
B.10
C.15
D.23
Ans.

2. Which day is today ?
A.Mon
B.Wed
C.Friday
D.Sunday
Ans.
```

I am using command ...

```
sed -e '/Ans./{r file2' -e:n -e 'n;bn' -e \} file1
```

**But the second o/p from 2 is reversed**

```
1 How many steps are in programming?
A.5
B.4
C.3
D.9
Ans.

1. Who is outside of the room ?
A.john
B.Mary
C.Scot
D.Fery
Ans.

**2. Which day is today ?**
A.Mon
B.Wed
C.Friday
D.Sunday
Ans.

**2 How many stairs in room?**
A.6
B.10
C.15
D.23
```

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this with `awk`

```
awk -v RS='' '
    FNR == NR { block[NR] = $0; next }
    { print block[FNR] "\n\n" $0 "\n" }
' file1 file2
```

Blocks are separated by empty lines (`RS=''`). First line (`FNR == NR`) stores the blocks of `file1` into the `block` array. For each block of `file2`, the second line prints the corresponding block in `file1` then the block in `file2`.

Notes:

- I'm assuming each file contains the same number of text blocks
- For a proper formatting, ensure that the last block in each file is followed by en empty line.

---

If there is a different number of blocks in each file, here is a (admittedly hackish) solution using `bash` and GNU tools `sed` and `paste`:

```
paste -z -d '\n' <(sed -z 's/\n\n/\n\x00/g' file1) <(sed -z 's/\n\n/\n\n\x00/g' file2)
```

The `sed` commands append a zero byte to the block separators (empty lines). `paste` uses that zero byte as a delimiter and prints each block in turn, separating them with a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close using `awk` in paragraph mode, with `getline` (it doesn't quite preserve the record separators - you may be able to do better with GNU awk, using the `RT` variable):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"} {print; if( (getline < "second") > -1) print}' first
1 How many steps are in programming?
A.5
B.4
C.3
D.9
Ans.

1. Who is outside of the room ?
A.john
B.Mary
C.Scot
D.Fery
Ans.

2 How many stairs in room?
A.6
B.10
C.15
D.23
Ans.

2. Which day is today ?
A.Mon
B.Wed
C.Friday
D.Sunday
Ans.
```

Comment: its Working fine

Comment: @Pawan Then why not accept this as an answer?

Comment: @Pawan Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script and output to illustrate the use of standard utility paste for this.  First the simple case of pasting lines alternately from 2 separate files.  Then all we need to do is make the paragraph, stanza input into a single line and use the paste method.  The gathering of lines in a group into a "superline" is done with a short perl script that transforms each line by replacing the newline with some other character, in this case "@".  Then we paste, and then we separate the superlines back into paragraphs. This is a useful tehcnique because most *nix commands operate at the line level. It is useful enough, in fact, that at our shop we have a utility "masuli" to make such superlines.

The data files are smaller in the interest of conserving visual space.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# @(#) s1       Demonstrate modular approach to multi-line data, perl, paste.

# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space, debug.
# export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
LC_ALL=C ; LANG=C ; export LC_ALL LANG
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }
em() { pe "$*" >&2 ; }
db() { ( printf " db, ";for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done;printf "\n" ) >&2 ; }
db() { : ; }
C=$HOME/bin/context && [ -f $C ] && $C paste perl

pl " Input data file data[12]:"
 head data[12]

pl " Results, proof of concept:"
paste -d'\n' data[12]

pl " Input data files data[34]:"
head data[34]

pl " Results, collect, paste, separate:"
paste -d'\n' <( perl -00 -wp -e 's/\n/@/g;s/@@/=\n/' data3 ) \
             <( perl -00 -wp -e 's/\n/@/g;s/@@/=\n/' data4 ) |
tee f1 |
perl -000 -wp -e 's/@/\n/g;s/=/\n\n/g;s/\n\n\n/\n\n/g'

exit 0
```

producing:

```
$ ./s1

Environment: LC_ALL = C, LANG = C
(Versions displayed with local utility "version")
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23
perl 5.20.2

-----
 Input data file data[12]:
==> data1 <==
1.1
1.2

==> data2 <==
2.1
2.2

-----
 Results, proof of concept:
1.1
2.1
1.2
2.2

-----
 Input data files data[34]:
==> data3 <==
3.1a
3.1b

3.2a
3.2b


==> data4 <==
4.1a
4.1b

4.2a
4.2b


-----
 Results, collect, paste, separate:
3.1a
3.1b

4.1a
4.1b

3.2a
3.2b

4.2a
4.2b
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl